# How to store objective-c block into NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

I want to store some blocks into a NSDictionary.When some events happened,the blocks can be called.But the following errors occurred when trying to a NSDictionary :

```
reason: '[<__NSDictionary0 0x157503950> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key defalut.'
```

Is it possible to store block into a data structure?

Comment: Try wrapping the block in a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your quote of the error is accurate (hopefully it's copied and pasted), this has nothing to do with blocks in the dictionary. You are using a misspelled key in a KVC access of the dictionary. Notice that the error references a key "defalut", which I assume should have been "default". Search for that misspelled key in your project.

Also, you should consider using symbolic constants for such key strings so you're sure the key is always the same everywhere you use it.